# Message Retreival Feature with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, netbeans, panels

I am developing an application which has a built in chatting feature.
The logic is simply to retrieve the messages and other details (more on that later) from a mySQL database and to display them in a jPanel on the jFrame
the database table named messages has the columns timestamp, tousername, fromusername, message(message body..up to 1000 characters long) and status (either read or unread).
[Interface Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNyMm.jpg)

i want to have a layout such that in the main panel (which has the lowered bevel border in the frame, as indicated in the picture) should consist of further panels ordered first by status (unread takes priority) and then by timestamp (descending)
the panels should contain the last message which was sent by the sender to the user, the name of the sender, the time of sending and the number of unread messages that that sender has sent the user
onclicking that panel, the chathead should open (new frame named chathead)

pretty noob here..any help would be grossly appreciated

Comment: So what is the question here? Try it yourself and post your coding issue if you have any

Comment: Welcome to SO. See the help pages for what it's about, the kinds of questions that can be asked, and how to ask them.